# Running user task on a core and minimally interrupted / preempted

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduling

I would like to run a long term task on a dedicated core and would like that task to be minimally interrupted / preempted. I can see 2 solutions. Which one is better or any other solution?

1) Set affinity and isolate core using isolcpus

2) Make the thread real time using SCHED_FIFO and set the priority high
- if this is the better choice how high the priority should be? Can I set it to 99?

What I am concerned about is being preempted by kernel threads, IPIs ...

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the first solution you mentioned, by adding parameter isolcpus = [CPU no.] during boot will instruct Linux scheduler to not run any task on that CPU unless requested by user using CPU Affinity. But this CPU may receive interrupts and that can also be avoided by setting IRQ Affinity, so that the isolated CPU doesn’t receive any interrupt. Finally in your code of the task you set the Affinity to the isolated CPU and you are good to go. 
But Even if you follow these steps, kernel tasks are executed on the isolated CPU core if you are not using a real-time kernel from RP_PREEMPT, hence it might not be possible to completely isolate a CPU core unless you are using RT kernel.
Refer - http://elinux.org/CPU_Shielding_capability

The second solution about using `SCHED_FIFO` scheduling policy and using a high priority value will still not prevent the kernel threads, Timer tick interrupts, IPIs etc., from pre-empting your task. Because the scheduling policies and priority is for kernel to schedule all other User-space processes and threads and does not apply to kernel threads or processes. 
So by setting high priority to your task does not mean you will get 100% CPU dedicated to your task. Also the alternative, manually setting the CPU mask of your task to a CPUSET in the system, can cause problems and suboptimal load balancer performance. Your task will still get interrupted from time to time by Linux code, including other tasks - such as the timer tick interrupt and the scheduler code, IPIs from other CPUs and stuff like work queue kernel threads, although the interruption should be quite minimal if you have don’t have much activity going on in your other cores.

But the cleanest way to achieve this should come from Kernel tweak which I found from this link http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799?page=0,2. Though I haven’t tried this personally, I think it’s worth giving a look at this article as well before you decide upon the method you will use.